# Stormpath Express: Save customData

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath

I'm running an express server with express-stormpath for auth and to store same custom data about the user.

How can I post data to the server and save them to stormpath?
Currently my post looks like this:

```
app.post('/post', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
   var stundenplan_data = req.body;
   console.log(stundenplan_data);
   req.user.customData.stundenplan = stundenplan_data;
   req.user.customData.save();
});
```

I'm getting the right data I want to post in the console.log but if I call the data in another get request the custom data is empty.

Comment: Can you pass a callback to the save() function, and see if it returns any errors?

Comment: No iam not getting any errors when unsing: res.locals.user.save(function(err, updatedUser) {
    if (!err) {
      updatedUser.customData.anotherfield;
      console.log("error");
    // undefined
    }
 });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of the `express-stormpath` library, what I'd do is this:

When you initialize Stormpath as middleware, add the following setting to automatically make customData available:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  ...,
  expandCustomData: true,  // this will help you out
}));
```

Modify your route code to look like this:

```
app.post('/post', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res, next) {
  var studentPlan = req.body;
  console.log(studentPlan);
  req.user.customData.studentPlan = studentPlan;
  req.user.customData.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);  // this will throw an error if something breaks when you try to save your changes
    } else {
      res.send('success!');
    }
  });
});
```

The reason your changes weren't working above is that you didn't expand the customData first. Stormpath requires a separate request to 'grab' your customData, so if you don't do that first, things will fail to save.

The above change ensures this happens for you automatically =)

Comment: Thank you so much! I hoped you would answer me! :D